# UBUNTU 22 Hotspot is not connecting

Tags: 22.04, hot-spot

On Ubuntu 22, When hotspot is created, it is discoverable by other devices. But when I try to connect it, the status turns to saved, but mobile device is not connected. I tried it with multiple devices but it's not working.
Restarting Network manager didn't help. Not sure if there is some config related to this function.

Comment: A bug report exists for this issue: [My machine as Wi-Fi Hotspot broken after upgrade to 22.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1971538)

Answer (score 0):

I've create a bug report for this issue.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1971538